# Should we keep the 'should create' jasmine tests created by the Angular CLI?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

We have written some Jasmine tests in our Angular project, but we have also kept all the 'should create' tests that were created by the Angular CLI. They look like this:

```
it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I want to know if there is any value in keeping these tests? Is there any safety in validating that a component is truthy? Or are they just there as an example to get you going?

Comment: Not necessary. Its just an example for what you are writing test cases

Comment: The value is that you know that angular was able to create your component instance. Imagin your component depends on a service (TestService ) but you dont provide it -> componet cant created -> test fails

Comment: Thanks for the answer @enno.void. So I see that as long as I do not override the provided service, the test will fail if there is a service that is not provided.

But most of the time I want to test my components in isolation, and I end up overriding the service by using the providers array in the TestBed. And if so, I guess there still is not much point in keeping these tests, are there?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to keep them. There is no advantage in deleting them, except that your code might get a bit shorter and as enno.void already mentioned, there are cases where this test can fail as well.